# Providing a customized config file for another package

Tags: packaging

We use Ubuntu at work and I will need to make the same configuration changes to many systems so I am packaging these.
One of the configuration changes I need to make is setting lightdm to autologin.
For me to package this change it seems I will need to clobber the existing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and replace it with the my customized lightdm.conf. This seems like a bad idea.

How can I do this in a way that is won't cause breakage and is inline with how the rest of the community is working?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is often done by creating a package that uses [`dpkg-divert`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/dpkg-divert.8.html) in its maintainer scripts to move the old config file aside:

- In your preinst, divert the file away.

  ```
  dpkg-divert --add --package $your_package_name --rename \
      --divert /path/to/file.disabled \
      /path/to/file
  ```
- In your postrm, divert the file back.

  ```
  dpkg-divert --remove --package $your_package_name --rename \
      /path/to/file
  ```

See: http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html

One solution that helps abstract `dpkg-divert` is the `config-package-dev` package created and maintained by MIT's Debathena project. They have a [thorough tutorial](http://debathena.mit.edu/config-package-dev/).

Comment: From the examples on the linked page it looks like the `--divert` option should be provided in both the preinst and postrm files.

Comment: There seems to be newer documentation in https://wiki.debian.org/ConfigPackages, which recommends installing the file to /etc/site/ and using symlinks rather than installing directly into /etc/. It also recommends using postinst rather than preinst and prerm rather than postrm.